# Dynamically inject sequelize databases by prefix in NestJS

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am trying to run a Server with NestJS and Sequelize. I have a database connection with the Tables `Actions` and `Locations` as a static created Module, which is working fine:

```js
@Module({
  imports:[
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: '192.168.1.201',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pasword',
      database: 'actions_db',
      models:[
        Actions,
        Locations,
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

But I will need these tables in multiple instances for a dynamic number of users.

So my question: Is it possible to have a Sequelize connection to a Database, which I can inject into my services over which I can access (and if necessary create) tables based on a prefix like `u1_Actions`, `u2_Actions`, `u3_Actions` and so on?

The structure of all actions tables are the same, but I want multiple instances.

Or is there a better way to do this?

I could just write all of this in one table, but this would result in a giant table, with a lot of unrelated data.